# Why is overflow: hidden not working on my div?

Tags: html, css

If you try to give `margin-left` to C1 div, it moves and overflow is hidden. But if you try to give `margin-left` to C2 div, it moves towards right, but overflow is not hidden, rather it moves in next line (behavior of `inline-block`).

So why is it not working on C2 div? Is there any way to solve this problem?

(Basically I want C1 and C2 div to be placed together and overflow should be hidden if I increase their widths, or if I give them margins).

Here's what I'm trying:

```css
.c1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666666;
  display: inline-block;
}
.c2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  display: inline-block;
}
.c3 {
  width: 180px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: block;
}
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c1">C1</div>
  <div class="c2">C2</div>
  <div class="c3">C3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the container (`.wrapper`).

> [**white-space**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
>
> The `white-space` property is used to describe how whitespace inside
>   the element is handled.
>
> ***`nowrap`***
>
> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text
>   wrapping) within text.
>
> <sub>*source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space*</sub>

To understand why, with `white-space: normal`, C2 wraps but C1 does not, see these posts:

- [Understanding the wrapping behavior of inline-block elements with overflow:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103210/understanding-the-wrapping-behavior-of-inline-block-elements)
- [Why are these inline-block divs wrapping in spite of their parent having overflow-x:scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395838/why-are-these-inline-block-divs-wrapping-in-spite-of-their-parent-having-overflo)

Here's an excerpt from an [answer by @BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35103380/3597276):

> - The value of `overflow` on a container doesn't influence *whether* or
>     *when* its contents overflow; it only changes how it and its contents are rendered, when overflow *does* occur.
> - So you have to force the inline-blocks to actually overflow the
>     container.
> - Since an inline-block has the same rigid physical structure as a block
>     container box, it's impossible for an inline-block to "break apart" or
>     wrap when it's the only inline-level box on a given line box.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Display Property.. Use Float property for example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.c1{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#666666;
   float:left;
   margin-left:10px;
   overflow:hidden;

    }
.c2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 220px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
 float:left;
   margin-left:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
    }
.c3{
    width: 180px;
    height: 210px;
    background-color: #333333;
    float:left;
   margin-left:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
    }
.wrapper{
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="c1">C1</div>
<div class="c2">C2</div>
<div class="c3">C3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please make a snippet.